# Regex to find the word immediately after a particular word

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to find the word immediately after a particular word  in a string using a regex. For example, if the word is 'my',

"This is my prayer"- prayer

"this is my book()"- book

Is it possible using regex?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The regex would be

```
(?<=\bmy\s+)\p{L}+
```

`\p{L}+` is a sequence of letters. The `\p{L}` is a [Unicode code point with the property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) "Letter", so it matches a letter in any language.

`(?<=\bmy\s+)` is a lookbehind assertion, that ensures thet word "my" is before

Comment: +1; added a word boundary so you don't match `army surplus` :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a look ahead REGEX:

```
(?<=my )\b\w+\b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
my\s+\b(\w+)\b
```

This captures the word after my in the first subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

For `my`,  use the following regex:

```
my (\w+)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `my` is taken from user input,

```
static string GetWordAfter(string word, string phrase)
{
    var pattern = @"\b" + Regex.Escape(word) + @"\s+(\w+)";
    return Regex.Match(phrase, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
}

...

string wordAfterMy = GetWordAfter("my", "this is my book()"); // gives book
```

This will return an empty string if there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

"this is my prayer"

```
.* (my )(\D*)( ).*
```

group2 in result will your word "prayer"

Comment: You use many unnecessary groups, OK, but why do you use `\D`, which is "Not a digit" ? What have digits to do with matching words?