# Selecting the word immediately after a keyword

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to extract the word immediately a keyword using R. I don't have a lot of experience with regular expressions so everything I've found so far doesn't help me much.  If I could get the function to return multiple instances that would be ideal.

For example if my keyword was `the` and my string was:

`The yellow log is in the stream`

It would return `yellow` and `stream`.

I found this [solution for c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395721/regex-to-find-the-word-immediately-after-a-particular-word) and it seems exactly like what I want but I'm having trouble implementing it in R.

Comment: try to show some code you have so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is non `regex` solution:

```
mytext <- "The yellow log is in the stream"
mykey <- "the"

x <- unlist(strsplit(mytext," "))

x[which(tolower(x)==mykey)+1]
```

Comment: This code actually makes sense to me so I selected this as the best.  Thank you.

Comment: Note that this will also return any punctuation immediately adjacent to the word after the key (so may require further cleaning before e.g. tabulating word frequency).

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str1, perl('(?<=\\b(?i)The )\\w+'))[[1]]
#[1] "yellow" "stream"
```

Or using `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(str1, '(?<=\\b(?i)The )\\w+')[[1]]
 #[1] "yellow" "stream"
```

EDIT: Changed based on @Roland's suggestion in the comments.

#### data

```
str1 <- 'The yellow log is in the stream'
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason this gives a "perl is deprecated" warning.

Comment: @brknparticle  I am using `stringr_0.6.2` and couldn't get any warning

Comment: @brknparticle  Can you try with the `stringi` method I just updated

Answer (score 4):

assign `key` to whatever string you want and use

```
key <- 'the'
p <- "The yellow log is in the stream" 
regmatches(p, gregexpr(sprintf('(?i)(?<=%s\\s)\\w+', key), p, perl = TRUE))[[1]]
# [1] "yellow" "stream"
```

or as @Roland points out, it would be safer to use a word boundary around your keyword to avoid this:

```
key <- 'the'
p <- "The yellow log is in the stream drinking absinthe and beer"
regmatches(p, gregexpr(sprintf('(?i)(?<=%s\\s)\\w+', key), p, perl = TRUE))[[1]]
# [1] "yellow" "stream" "and"   

regmatches(p, gregexpr(sprintf('(?i)(?<=\\b%s )\\w+', key), p, perl = TRUE))[[1]]
# [1] "yellow" "stream"
```

Comment: I'd use `"(?<=(\\b[Tt]he ))\\w+"`. The word boundary seems necessary here.

Comment: Thank you for, this returns exactly what I need.  What does the [[1]] at the end do?

Comment: @brknparticle `regmatches` is interpreting a list of match data from `gregexpr` so it returns a list. you can just select the first element of the list to get your matches

Answer (score 2):

Try this:  this returns 'yellow' and  'stream'

```
x <- "The yellow log is in the stream"

regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?:(?:T|t)he)\\s(\\w+)", x, perl = TRUE))[[1]]
## [1] "The yellow" "the stream"
```

Answer (score 2):

The **qdapRegex** package I maintain has a regular expression `after_` in the `regex_supplement` dictionary that is perfect for this.  You can use `rm_` to make your own `after_the` function:

```
library(qdapRegex)

x<- "The yellow log is in the stream"
after_the <- rm_(pattern = S("@after_", "[Tt]he"), extract = TRUE)
after_the(x)

## [[1]]
## [1] "yellow" "stream"
```

The `S` function is a wrapper for `sprintf` that allows you to easily pass elements (like the work "the" in this case) to the base regex producing:

```
S("@after_", "the", "The")
## [1] "(?<=\\b(the|The)\\s)(\\w+)"
```

**EDIT**

```
library(qdapRegex)

x<- c("The yellow log is in the stream", "I like the one box for a pack")
after_ <- rm_(extract = TRUE)
after_the(x)

after_ <- rm_(extract = TRUE)

words <- c("the", "a", "one")

setNames(lapply(words, function(y){
    after_(x, pattern = S("@after_", y, TC(y)))
}), words)


## $the
## $the[[1]]
## [1] "yellow" "stream"
## 
## $the[[2]]
## [1] "one"
## 
## 
## $a
## $a[[1]]
## [1] NA
## 
## $a[[2]]
## [1] "pack"
## 
## 
## $one
## $one[[1]]
## [1] NA
## 
## $one[[2]]
## [1] "box"
```

Comment: This sounds pretty interesting.  Could I pass in a list of key words here, for instance `c("the", "a", "one")`  and have it select after each?

Comment: See my edit for this approach.  You'd still want to `loop` it

Comment: Okay excellent.  I've already solved my problem, but this looks like a pretty elegant approach.  I'll see if can make it work for me.  Thank you.