# Regex to find the word inmmediately after a set of words using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find the string right after a set of words using regex.

For example, if the words are "these" and "the",

> 1. thesePeople -> People
> 2. theApple -> Apple

Is it possible?

The main issue here is "the" is a substring of "these". I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395721/regex-to-find-the-word-immediately-after-a-particular-word) and made my attempt:

```
@"(?<=the|these)\w+"
```

But this regex gives "sePeople" to me for the first case, and I cannot go further. Can anyone help?

Comment: is the second word always upper case? because `[A-Z]\w+`

Comment: Not possible to make greedy lookbehind. One way is to match everything using `(?:these|the)(?<word>\w+)` regex (note that these comes first in regex) and extract `word` group from the match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to get every character after the or these:

```
the(se){0,1}(\w+)
```

The is always matched. If 'se' is also present, it is matched by the first capture group. Everything afterwards is then matched by the second capture group.

With this one you can also capture words that are not preceeded by the or these:

```
(?>the(?>se){0,1}){0,1}(\w+)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, but after my attempt of your suggestion on this web(https://dotnetfiddle.net), I still got "sePeople" for your regex.

Comment: Your link doesn't work. I tested it with regex101.com, works like a charm. Make sure to access the third capture group, this is the one containing the result

Comment: Or use this regex: (?>the(?>se){0,1}){0,1}(\w+), it ignores the first two capture groups and only matches the word. I also updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

If all your words are formatted as above this (`[A-Z]\w+`) simple regex would work:

```
string[] words = new string[]{"thesePeople", "theApple"};
foreach(string word in words)
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(word, @"[A-Z]\w+", RegexOptions.None).Groups[0].Value);
```

Outputs:

> People
>
> Apple

https://dotnetfiddle.net/aevqlT

Comment: Thank you for answering but sadly they are not in this format. It is just a simple example.

Comment: Are you forced into regex? Some code could solve this issue much easier.